# Global in-memory counter that is thread-safe and flushes to mysql every x increments

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

Is it possible to create an in-memory counter that all servlets will use?

This global counter will keep track of pageviews for a web application, and the counter will be specific to the currently logged in user. i.e. **the collection will have a key for each user.**

```
globalCounterMap[userId].incrementCounter += 1;
```

At a certain interval or pageview count, I want to save the current count to mysql (insert a new row) e.g.:

```
table_pageviews [id, userId, pageview_count, date]
```

So this counter will then get reset to 0 after the flush.

So if I have a BaseServlet that all servlets will inherit from, how would I define this field? (final, static?)

**Is the ConcurrentHashMap suitable?**  Maybe I can store an AtomicLong for the value for each entry.

During the flush, I can use the getAndSet of the atomic long by setting to 0, and saving the value that I 'get': http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html

Do I have to synchronize during the flush to mysql process?  (Say I do this every 1K pageviews)

**Update**

So even if I have 10 servers, each with their own in-memory counters, things will still work since they will all eventually flush their counts to the db and then I will simply aggregate the rows to get the final counts.

Comment: why not have a MemcacheD server, and flush it every hour or minute to DB? MemcachedD IO is fast enough, and it will always hold total page views of a user.

Answer (score 5):

As Konstantin said, something like redis may be a better solution.  Cassandra counters are also a very good way to do this sort of thing.

If you want to do this with java, here is some code that increments the count safely and without blocking,

```
class Counter {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

    //increment the count for the user
    public void increment(String user) {
        while(true) {
            AtomicInteger current = counts.get(user);
            if(current == null) {
                //new user, initialize the count
                counts.putIfAbsent(user, new AtomicInteger());
                continue;
            }

            int value = current.incrementAndGet();
            if(value > 0) {
                //we have incremented the counter
                break;
            } else {
                //someone is flushing this key, remove it
                //so we can increment on our next iteration
                counts.replace(user, current, new AtomicInteger());
            }

        }
    }

    //call this periodically to flush keys to the database
    //this will empty the counts map so that users who
    //are not active do not take up space
    public void flush() {
        Map<String, Integer> toFlush = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
            String user = entry.getKey();
            AtomicInteger currentCount = entry.getValue();
            //stop incrementing this count
            counts.remove(user, currentCount);
            //if someone is trying to increment this AtomicInteger after
            //we remove it, they will see a -ve value from incrementAndGet, and 
            //will know their increment did not succeed
            Integer count = currentCount.getAndSet(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            toFlush.put(user, count);
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> clearedEntry : toFlush.entrySet()) {
            writeToDb(clearedEntry.getKey(), clearedEntry.getValue());
        }

    }

    public void writeToDb(String user, int count) {
        //do something with the count here
    }


}
```

The code is fairly complicated, and as Peter Lawrey said, a simple map protected with a synchronized keyword is likely to perform well enough and be much easier to maintain.

Comment: for the flush, couldn't I make copy of the existing map, and then reset the live map, and then flush the copy?  and make sure process happends on a single thread.

Comment: if by reset you mean call map.clear(), then no, that wouldn't be thread safe.  You need to know the AtomicIntegers that you remove from the map to set their value to MIN_VALUE. If by reset you mean something like counters = new ConcurrentHashMap() after you copy, then yes, but counters would have to be volatile, and it doesn't really buy you anything

Comment: actually, if you do counters = new ConcurrentHashMap(), that is probably not going to be thread safe either

Comment: So it might be worth it to wrap the flush in synchronize then?  If there are 10K items, it would be just for a 1ms probably :)  unless that won't work for some reason?

Comment: the race would not be between different calls to flush, the race is between flush and increment

Comment: so if you say its ok if you miss some counts during a copy of the map i.e. 1 second of results, would that make things easier somehow?

Comment: hmm..maybe not, since the concurrent map locks at a more localized level (striped I think was the term is), I guess doing it a key at a time makes sense.

Comment: is toFlush safe not being a concurrent collection?

Comment: yes, toFlush is only used in the one method, so it is never modified by multiple threads

Comment: so in my application, I have to fire up a thread that sleeps for x minutes and hits that method right?  I can't have this in a cron job since it is out of process I presume?

Comment: look at ScheduledExecutorServce.scheduleAtFixedRate

Comment: I'd do a toFlush = counters; counters = new ConcurrentHashMap(). Then sleep for a while, letting any threads updating AtomicInteger's in toFlush finish. Oh, and counters would be declared volatile.

Comment: how long do you sleep for?  if your algorithm depends on sleep, then it isn't safe.

Answer (score 2):

I would use synchronized to start with as this is the simplest approach.  Otherwise you are likely to have issues with pages being used between collecting the data and flushing the result. You can use getAndSet() but what are you going to do if you expect it to be 128 and its now 130?

Another option is to not worry about it being entirely thread safe and a few page updates are lost, not worry about.

Another option is to keep the total written to the database so far and only send the differences tot eh database.  That way, there is no need to reset the numbers (however the snapshot may not be all at once)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible; but not advisable.   Using my mental superpowers I deduce that you try to implement some statistics gathering tool, and you like to have statistic accumulated per user per time interwal.

You can use approach with servlet filter and synchronized method, which will update database from time to time
But you will run into problems with:
   - application clustering over several servers 
   - managing database connections and transactions
( you will not develop this tool if you do not need realtime statistics, otherwise you can just stick  with log processing every 24 hours)

This is better done with NoSQL database like redis,  and  atomic increments of value of some key.  Just  use "userid:startOfIntervalInMisllisecondsSince1970" as key, and increment this value.
   - it is fast
   - atomic
   - data is always safe
   - no need to share anything and synchronize across load balanced  cluster or between multiple  threads  in your container.

Comment: Well I'm inserting a new row into the db, so it doesn't matter if other servers are doing the same as the final value will come from the SUM of all rows, no?

Comment: from your data model I can deduce that you will end up with a load of entries with same userid & time but ddiferent IDs.  You can later run aggregation query, bu this can prove not suitable for your data sizes

Answer (score 0):

Being exact about the counter is not necessary in this case.

I would go for a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but the `AtomicInteger` might not be necessary. Assuming requests of a client are delivered on the same server, you can count the numer of visited page for that client with a relaxed thread safety. You probably want to exclude count to resource request (e.g. style sheets, etc.) and count only content pages. So while two concurrent requests of the *same* client might conflict and an update get lost, it's rarely the case and the relaxed scheme is good enough. That said, implementing a thread-safe scheme with an `AtomicInteger` probably won't impact performance anyway given that the lock is acquired for very short period of time (benchmark anyone?).

The problem is that the map of counter is **global**, so that won't scale if you have several servers.

- One option to handle this is to have *sticky sessions* (anyway a good practice). This way, requests of a client always reach the same server. We're basically in the same situation as the previously.
- Another option to handle this is to *counter the number of page visited on the client-side*. You browser request the server to save the value from time to time (possibly sending a value and a time stamp). You can intercept with javascript when the user leave the page/site to make sure you flush the data to the server (see `onBeforeUnload`).